# Allowing a user to access a table in DB2

Tags: db2

I'm using DB2 10.5 and have two users: db2admin and db2user. db2admin is an Administrator of the Windows 7 Operating System while db2user is a normal user. I have created a database named DB1 using db2admin and now I want to allow db2user to access the TB1 table in it.

I used the following command for that:

```
db2 => connect to db1 user db2admin using db2admin
db2 => grant select, insert, update, delete on tb1 to user db2user
```

The Result when executed following commands:

```
connect to db1 user db2user using db2user
SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES WHERE AUTHID = SESSION_USER AND AUTHIDTYPE = 'U'

AUTHID     AUTHIDTYPE PRIVILEGE   GRANTABLE OBJECTNAME
DB2USER    U          UPDATE      N         TB1
DB2USER    U          SELECT      N         TB1
DB2USER    U          INSERT      N         TB1
DB2USER    U          DELETE      N         TB1
```

According to that result set db2user seems to have privileges to the TB1. However, when I tried to access it programmatically using db2user, following error was thrown:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2USER.TB1
```

According to the error code there is no TB1 in the DB2USER schema.

Following commands confirmed that:

```
connect to db1 user db2user using db2user
db2 => list tables

0 record(s) selected.
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? Any guidance on how to get this working is much appreciated.

UPDATE: I have already tried accessing the same table with db2admin and it works perfectly. What I want to get done is to access it using db2user, but db2user shouldn't create the tables; that's db2admin's job. So how can I get that working? How can db2admin put the tables inside db2user's schema?

Comment: The answers below are correct.  It's best practice for users to use fully-qualified table names (`schema.table`) when issuing queries instead of relying on `CURRENT SCHEMA`.  Similarly, when you create a table, specify the schema explicitly:  `CREATE TABLE schema.table (...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQLCODE `-204`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00204n.html) means that the object cannot be found. My guess is that since you didn't provide a schema, your table was implicitly placed in the `db2admin` schema. Try doing

```
SELECT * FROM db2admin.tb1
```

And see if that works.

Comment: I have already tried that and it's working. I have update the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You created the table from user DB2ADMIN and the implicit schema will be used. In this case, the table is called db2admin.tb1

When you perform a select from the DB2USER, the implicit schema is the same user name, and that table does not exist.

Comment: Thanks! I have already tried that and it's working. Please see the updated question.